# cucumber is_admin? testing

Tags: rspec

I don't know where to put this post, but theme of this more similar to
my issue.

I have trite signin system, like this:

> ApplicationController:
>   include SessionsHelper

private

helper_method :current_user

def current_user
 @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end

> SessionsHelper:
>     def is_admin?
>      @current_user && @current_user.id == 1
>     end
>
> features/support/env.rb:
>   World(SessionsHelper)

So, if I test

> is_admin?.should be_true

it returns:

expected nil to be true (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
      ./features/step_definitions/users/add_user.rb:23:in `/^I should
signin$/'
      features/users/add_user.feature:13:in`And I should signin'

But I signed in! Why? What's the way to test authentication system from
scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know where to put this post, but theme of this more similar to
>   my issue.
>   The cucumber mailing list is:
>   http://groups.google.com/group/cukes

But I can tell you that your problem is a scope issue.  Your is_admin? 
method
that is added to cucumber's world does not have access to your 
application
controller's @current_user variable.